Knife tool does not snap to vertex/edge/etc

Snap to Vertex is on. I have also tried snapping to the grid and the edge. When I hover over the vertex nothing is happening.
I've dissolved the double vertices. Nothing happens if I select the start vertex and then choose the knife-tool.

Hello could you please tell from which to which vertex you're trying to cut and share the file?

Are you trying to cut multiple objects at once?

The settings for Snapping are just for moving, rotating or scaling. The Knife tool does not use those settings at all. But by default it snaps to vertices (indicated by the green square changing its color and getting a red outline) and to edges (indicated by a larger green square and the edge showing in yellow). Holding Ctrl will ignore this snapping.

@NiklasFriedrichs
I am trying to cut just one object

@GordonBrinkmann It does not show my cursor on the screenshot but it does not do the default thing - change of colour and a red outline - when I hover over the vertices.

Could it be you have accidentally used the shortcut Shift+K for the Knife tool instead of K? Because then it will only work on selected geometry, and in your screenshot nothing is selected.

@GordonBrinkmann I do not think so, I tried multiple times and with the vertex selected before choosing the knife tool. I think it was a bug. I tried turning the program off and on and it didn't help.
However, when I started working on other objects in the same file (using different tools) and later came back to the one I wanted to cut. I don't know how it worked as it should - it was shaping to vertices and edges.
